# Error recieving Object via ObjectInputStream from server

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I'm writing a simple utility package for simplification of the java.io.Socket api but have run into following speed bump: I am so far able to send a Message Class (just contains a field of type Object which represents any kind of data) to the server (I am testing using Strings) and it's able to read it in. However, when I try to read the Message back again, the stream doesn't recognize any data coming through (I'm checking with in.available() > 0). Any help would be appreciated!

```
public class Client {

    private Socket client;
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;

    public Client (String hostName, int port) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Establishing connection to server at " + hostName + ":" + port + "...");
        client = new Socket(hostName, port);
        System.out.println("Client connected. Client: " + client);

        this.out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        this.out.flush();
        this.in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    }

    public Object getFromServer () throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        return in.readObject();
    }

    public void sendToServer (Object o) throws IOException {
        out.writeObject(o);
        out.flush();
    }

    public boolean dataAvailable () throws IOException {
        return in.available() > 0;
    }

    public void close () throws IOException {
        client.close();
    }
}
```

Server-side thread for client handling (I don't need to include the Servers code as it doesn't have to do with input-output:

```
public class ClientHandler extends Thread {

    private Socket client;
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;

    public ClientHandler (Socket socket) throws IOException {
        super();
        this.client = socket;
        this.out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        this.out.flush();
        this.in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    }

    @Override
    public void run () {
        String currentMessage = "";
        while (currentMessage != "/exit") {
            try {
                currentMessage = (String)((Message)in.readObject()).getData();
                out.writeObject(new Message(currentMessage.toUpperCase()));
                out.flush();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.err.println("ClassNotFoundException occured while processing client input");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("IOException occured while processing client input");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException occured while trying to close client socket");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Testing class for Client:

```
public class ClientMain {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Client client = new Client("localhost", 9090);

        BufferedReader sysIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String userMessage = "";

        while (userMessage != "/exit") {
            if (client.dataAvailable()) /*this if-statement never returns true*/ {
                String serverMessage = (String)((Message)client.getFromServer()).getData();
                System.out.println(serverMessage);
            }

            if (sysIn.ready()) {
                userMessage = sysIn.readLine();
                client.sendToServer(new Message(userMessage));
            }
        }

        client.close();
    }
}
```

Before anyone askes, my Message class does implement the Serializable interface so that's probably not the issue.

Comment: *Remove* the `available()` check. It adds no value whatsoever.

Comment: It creates an unblocked read. That's what I was going for

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it. In the ClientMain class (in the main method), I split the user input reading and the server reading into two threads. I made the userMessage String static volatile and now it works for some reason. If anyone could answer though to say why my approach didn't work that would be very helpful.

Comment: I might have been a tad eager to post this on StackOverflow :D